# Optimize SQLite queries for number of records in time intervals

Tags: sql, sqlite, query-optimization

I have a table which stores a set of events whose schema can be simplified for this example to

```
CREATE TABLE events (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  time INTEGER NOT NULL,
  data BLOB
);
CREATE INDEX by_time ON events(time);
```

Given a time interval `min` to `max`, I want to get the number of events in each 1-hour interval between `min` and `max` (concrete example below).
The most obvious way to achieve this that I can think of is to compute the required intervals in my code and then for each one run the query

```
SELECT count(*) FROM events WHERE ? <= time AND time < ?;
```

Is there a faster way to achieve this by making SQLite deal with splitting the interval into smaller chunks?
If this makes the solution simpler, we can assume `min` and `max` are exactly at the start/end of an hour interval.

#### Example

Suppose `events` contains events with times

```
100, 200, 1600, 3000,
3800, 4000,
7400,
15000, 15200, 17000,
20400,
22300, 23000
```

Then I would want a query with `min = 3600, max = 21600` to return something like

```
start |  end  | count
-------------------
 3600 |  7200 | 2
 7200 | 10800 | 1
10800 | 14400 | 0
14400 | 18000 | 3
18000 | 21600 | 1
```

It doesn't matter exactly what the format of the output is as long as it contains the required counts and a way to identify which interval they refer to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to get the time intervals and then `LEFT` join the table to aggregate:

```
WITH 
  cte(min, max) AS (SELECT 3600, 21600),
  intervals AS (
    SELECT min from_time, min + 3600 to_time, max
    FROM cte
    WHERE min + 3600 <= max
    UNION ALL
    SELECT to_time, to_time + 3600, max
    FROM intervals
    WHERE to_time + 3600 <= max
  )
SELECT i.from_time, i.to_time,
       COUNT(e.id) count 
FROM intervals i LEFT JOIN events e
ON e.time >= i.from_time AND e.time < i.to_time
GROUP BY i.from_time, i.to_time;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=7496ab287dd45b991f26a88bf95f6da3).